# jquery submit handler not working

Tags: jquery, submit, handler

I'm trying to submit a form using jquery submit function. When I submit the form without handler everything works. Submit function with handler doesn't submit at all. Also it doesn't invoke the handler code.

This is the code that doesn't work

jsfiddle.net/ge5575nj/2/

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make another function to handle submit event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('keydown', '#squery', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             $('#searchform').submit()
        }
    });
    $('#searchform').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Hi');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. There is no need to use event.preventDefault with a handler. If you want to prevent the submit return false from your handler and if you want to proceed return true.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('keydown', '#squery', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

      /* with handler */
      $('#searchform').submit(function(event) {
        alert("hi");
        return true;
      });

      /* without handler */
      $('#searchform').submit()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/search/" id="searchform">
  <input autocomplete="off" id="squery" type="text" name="q" class="form-control">
  <input name="qtype" id="searchType" hidden value="0">
</form>
```